# How can I subset via Boolean series for multiple successive rounds for without assigning an intermediate DF?

Tags: python, pandas

Often I need to filter or subset a dataframe using Boolean criteria (eg, `df[~df.filterColumn1.duplicated()]`), but sometimes I cannot filter it further without assigning the intermediate DF to a temporary object (or without repeating code).

Let's say I want to output rows where a column matches a substring, but some rows in this column are null.  `df.yourColumn.str.contains('substringToMatch')` will throw an error if any of the values in the column are NaN (or blank). (NOTE: I'm not looking to solve this problem, necessarily! I'm just using it as an example for when I need a temporary DF.)

Thus, here I need to first index the DF for where there are not null values in this column, and then subsequently index THAT filtered DF for rows where substring matching is True for the "comments" column.

Here is a DF to exemplify this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'modSeq': {0: 'DC[+57]QNLKLIPQRGVS[-2]EAVE', 1: 'DGALQPPFQEPIVGRE', 2: 'DIAPR[-43]AK', 3: 'DQLALI[+16]WFAYLE', 4: 'DQLALIWFAYLE', 5: 'EC[+57]YGL[+16]KLIPE', 6: 'EDC[+57]QNLK', 7: 'EDC[+57]QNLKLIPQR'}, 'area': {0: 551, 1: 8374246, 2: 416840, 3: 546654, 4: 293998, 5: 189995, 6: 59548, 7: 26552}, 'comments': {0: 'weird, both jump around', 1: 'unmodified', 2: nan, 3: 'both go up! Problems recalculating; 190122', 4: 'unmodified', 5: nan, 6: 'unmodified', 7: 'unmodified; Problems recalculating; 190122'}})
```

```
                        modSeq     area                                    comments
0  DC[+57]QNLKLIPQRGVS[-2]EAVE      551                     weird, both jump around
1             DGALQPPFQEPIVGRE  8374246                                  unmodified
2                 DIAPR[-43]AK   416840                                         NaN
3            DQLALI[+16]WFAYLE   546654  both go up! Problems recalculating; 190122
4                 DQLALIWFAYLE   293998                                  unmodified
5         EC[+57]YGL[+16]KLIPE   189995                                         NaN
6                 EDC[+57]QNLK    59548                                  unmodified
7            EDC[+57]QNLKLIPQR    26552  unmodified; Problems recalculating; 190122
```

```
tempDF = df[~df.comments.isna()]
tempDF[tempDF.comments.str.contains('190122')]
```

That gives me the correct result I'm looking for:

```
              modSeq    area                                    comments
3  DQLALI[+16]WFAYLE  546654  both go up! Problems recalculating; 190122
7  EDC[+57]QNLKLIPQR   26552  unmodified; Problems recalculating; 190122
```

However, I have to assign a temporary DF in order to index the second boolean Series correctly.

How could I do something like this all in one command?

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, where the problem is having `nan`s mess up your string accessor, the solution can be straightforward - replace `nan` with an empty string:

`df[df.comments.fillna('').str.contains('190122')]`

Generally though, I don't like intermediate variables myself, but the concerns for me are more cosmetic.  If the reason you want to avoid the intermediate variable name is that it is unsightly, [method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining) may be what you'd want (if some other concern, let me know).  It's much uglier in this specific case but generally can lead to two-step code IMO.

```
(
    df
    .query("~comments.isna()", engine='python')
    .query("comments.str.contains('190122')", engine='python')
)
```